# Filtering duplicate records while importing data from source table to target table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

This may be a simple query to some of you. But I am not strong in Sql, so expecting some solution for my problem.

I have 2 tables, `ProductVenueImport` and `SupplierVenueImport`.

We are dumping all the records from `SupplierVenueImport` to `ProductVenueImport` using **MERGE** clause and a `Temp` table. `Temp` will have valid records from `SupplerVenuImport` and from `Temp` table we are importing records to `ProductVenueImport`.

But before importing data to `ProductVenueImport` from `Temp` table I need to check for the duplicate records in my target (`ProductVenueImport`).

For example if I am importing a record with name as 'A', I need to look into `ProductVenueImport` whether 'A' already existing or not. If it is not existing then only I need to insert 'A' otherwise not.

Could somebody tell me how to do this?

Is using **Cursors** only the option?

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: Can u provide ur current query so that suggestions can be given accordingly. Also do u simply need to remove duplicate records from ur source table before inserting in target table? If yes i believe it could be done without cursor. Just try searching on net for the same and better try by yourself.

Comment: @NitinAgrawal, I need to remove the duplicates from 'Temp' table and at the same time I need to backup those records into another 'Temp' table for further usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Temp` table itself doesn't have duplicates, you could use MERGE like this:

1. Insert non-existing products.
2. Do a NO-OP in case of an existing product.
3. Use `$action` in the OUTPUT clause to mark which rows were considered for insertion (and inserted) and which for update (but not really updated).

This is what I mean:

```
DECLARE @noop int;  -- needed for the NO-OP below

MERGE INTO ProductVenueImport AS tgt
USING Temp AS src
ON src.ProductID = tgt.ProdutID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (    column1,     column2, ...)
  VALUES (src.column1, src.column2, ...)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET @noop = @noop  -- the NO-OP instead of update
OUTPUT $action, src.column1, src.column2, ...
  INTO anotherTempTable
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do this :

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTTBL(FEILD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5)
SELECT (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5) FROM TEMP WHERE CRITERIAFIELD NOT IN(SELECT     DISTINCT CRITERIAFIELD FROM PRODUCTTBL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to check for duplicates in a table

select columnname from tablename 
group by columnname
having count(columnname) >1

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I am not getting the question right, can't you use the merge statement on the source table with "When not matched Insert" to insert the new records alone

so in your case it should be like this

```
merge into ProductVenueImport using temp on (<condition for duplicate>)
when not matched then insert <clause>;
```

the merge clause will make sure that no duplicate records are inserted into your source table.